# How do I define custom configuration directives for my Apache module?

Tags: c++, c, apache, delphi, apache2

What I want to do is pass some settings to my module from httpd.conf, something like:

```
<Location /path>
  SetHandler mymodule-handler # based on this, the module will kick in and "try" to read settings
  MyCustomStringSetting "AStringValue"
  MyCustomIntegerSetting 2012
  # more
</Location>
```

How can I get "AStringValue" and "2012" from within the module?

Comment: @kobik no, I want to use apache's API to get the values, something like ap_get_config_value("MyCustomStringSetting"); which will return "AStringValue", but I'm ok with anything similar that will help me get the values

Comment: @kobik apache loads modules via LoadModule directive in configuration file(s), each module registers hooks, so the module can ask apache using API: "hey, what's the setting for MyCustomStringSetting" to which apache responds: "Here it is", my trouble is, how to ask apache that information

Comment: @kobik sorry, I didn't want it to sound that way, I didn't knew how else to explain what I want to achieve, it's pretty complex that's why I need help myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a complete example (with source) from "Apache: The Definitive Guide":

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch15_04.htm

The example module mod_reveal implements two commands, RevealServerTag and RevealTag.

In the server configuration, these two new commands can be used:

```
<VirtualHost :9000>
DocumentRoot /home/camilla/WWW/docs
RevealTag H2Main
RevealServerTag H2
</VirtualHost>
```

And then processed by the module.